# How to remove \n from the string using string module

Tags: python, string

```
import string
s = "Salut\n\tComment ca va ?"
t = str.maketrans("\n"," ")
y = str.maketrans("\t"," ")
#z = str.maketrans("\n\t","  ")
s = s.translate(t).translate(y)
```

My Out > `'Salut  Comment ca va ?'`
Expected > `'Salut Comment ca va ?'` # only one space after the `Salut`

After `maketrans` we need to give space, why cant we give a null

Disclaimer I can use replace and regex for this but that is not the case

```
#with replace
s.replace('\n', '').replace('\t','')
#with regex
regex = re.compile(r'[\n\t]')
regex.sub("", s)
```

Comment: You don't need to import string here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with a dict that maps to `None`.

```
import string
s = "Salut\n\tComment ca va ?"

t =  {"\t":None,
      "\n": " "}
y = str.maketrans(t)
s = s.translate(y)
print(s)
```

Or if you don't want to use a dict you can do it all in one line (as per [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)) like so:
`y = str.maketrans("\n"," ","\t") # third argument chars are mapped to None`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you replace both (\n and \t) with a space.

```py
s.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

another minimal and more general option is to

```
' '.join(s.split())


s = "Salut\n\tComment ca va ?"
' '.join(s.split())
'Salut Comment ca va ?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace`.

```
import string
s = "Salut\n\tComment ca va ?"
t = str.maketrans("\n"," ")
y = str.maketrans("\t"," ")
#z = str.maketrans("\n\t","  ")
s = s.translate(t).translate(y)
print('Before:', s)
s=s.replace("  ", " ") #just added this line
print('After:', s)
```

But if you don't add extra white space during translation, you won't need this.

```
Before: Salut  Comment ca va ?
After: Salut Comment ca va ?
```